# Do I need to set "mappedBy" field on target entity by myself?

Tags: java, jpa, one-to-many

Given the following "parent" JPA entity:

```java
@Entity
public class Parent {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REMOVE })
    private List<Child> children;

}
```

and the following "child" JPA entity:

```java
@Entity
public class Child {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Parent parent;

    private String name;
}
```

I would have expected, that when persisting a Parent instance with Children, the `parent` field of the Child instance would automatically be set to the Parent instance (or the Parent's instance ID on SQL level) - but that's not the case.

Is that the documented behaviour or am I missing something?

To make it work, I have to explicitly set the `parent` field in every linked Child instance, e.g. using @PrePersist:

```java
@PrePersist
public void assignChildren() {
    this.children.forEach(c -> c.setParent(this));
}
```

Comment: Try adding @JoinColumn at your manytoone side and give a column and check. Please let me know whether it is working or not.

Comment: Adding @JoinColumn doesn't change the outcome, just the column name (from PARENT to the name given by JoinColumn).

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

In Hibernate, the developer is responsible for keeping the [bidirectional associations in sync on both sides](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.1/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#associations-one-to-many-bidirectional):

> Whenever a bidirectional association is formed, the application developer must make sure both sides are in-sync at all times.

This doesn't change if you are setting the cascade option. This option make sure that an entity in the association gets updated when the parent gets updated, but it doesn't keep the association in sync.

You can change this behaviour [enabling byte-code enhancements](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.1/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#BytecodeEnhancement-dirty-tracking-bidirectional):
Hibernate will manage the association and make sure that both sides stay in sync whenever one side is updated.

Personally, I prefer to have a method `.addChild` (without the `@PrePersist`) and make sure that the associations are in-sync at all time and not just before a persist.